# Win8 Javascript Metro App, with C# WinRT Component and SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a Windows 8 Store App. The front-end (main project) of this app is in HTML5/Javascript. And I'm following [this guide by Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx) to create a C# WinRT component that wraps SQLite calls and behave as a **controller**. The front-end calls this component via Javascript, to update data, and get presentation content.

So there are 2 projects in my solution, 'main' in javascript, and 'db' in C#. I've managed to get SQLite working according to the guide. The reason I have this structure is that I'm trying to port an app from iOS to Win8. The 'controller' part is an isolated component from the get-go, and it's already ported to C#.

However, there is one caveat. Because of [this known problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2738078), I have to remove the reference to C++ Runtime v11 from the 'db' project to make it compilable. Though it runs fine in the development machine.

Then I got this test machine (samsung xe700t1a to be exact, Intel i5), I discovered that when 'debugging remote' on this test machine, Visual Studio won't deploy SQLite3. As a result, my SQLite calls fail with error: `"Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"`.

According to the guide I mentioned previously, the point SQLite was made available via WinRT extension, is to make deployment automatic.

I'm wondering why this happens and how to make it correct? I'm also wondering if there's any certification problems for Windows Store for apps in this structure?

I also came across [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e165e663-f06f-4c02-9a2d-aefa86f613a9/) and [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766435/cannot-use-sqllite-in-a-background-task) suggesting that it's currently not possible to use SQLite in a WinRT component. But it's too late for me to change now, and this project won't be possible without a hybrid structure.

Comment: On another note, because there are restrictions on accessing `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` folder, I don't even know what's deployed with my app when remote debugging.

Comment: You can open the command prompt as administrator and manually navigate to the WindowsApps folder. You just won't see it listed if you do Dir or use the file explorer.

Comment: @JimWooley, thank you. But it doesn't look like RemoteDebugger is deploying my app there. I can't find the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the hint from [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766435/cannot-use-sqllite-in-a-background-task), and it's very straightforward.

What I have to do, is to create another project in the solution, with Output Type set to C# Class Library. Move the reference to SQLite for WinRT, and sqlite-net (nuget) wrapper to this new project. After that, I have to manually go through classes in sqlite-net, and change all the 'internal' classes to 'public'.

For the original **controller** project, I add `using myclasslib;` so that class definitions are found.

Apparently this workaround will work flawlessly. SQLite3 is deployed, and there's no warning against missing reference.